# WPF ObjectDataProvider that supports linq filtering?

Tags: wpf, objectdataprovider, cascadingdropdown, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Is there an WPF ObjectDataProvider that supports "Where" I mean like in asp.net there is an option to have a dataprovider that supports defining the results?

What I actually need is two ComboBoxes that when I choose a value in the first it limits the second one.
Say I have a parent table Category and a child table Group. I want that when the user chooses a value in the category combo box, the values in the group should be only where Group.CategoryId = [Selected category Id].

And notice that I am talking about wpf toolkit DataGridComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) that has [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx) event, and can be explicitly refreshed by calling it's [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.view.aspx).[Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.refresh.aspx) method.

[(Answer credit)](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31)